# What is causing this mysterious vertical offset on these buttons?

Tags: html, css

I have four elements which are displayed as buttons. Two them are `<button>`s, one is an `<a>` and one is an `<input type="submit">`.

The text of the `<a>` is *ever so slightly* offset vertically relative the others, and I can't figure out why. This occurs in Chrome, Firefox, Safari and IE 11.

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Buttons</title>
    <style>
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border:0;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  border-spacing:0;
  font-size:inherit;
  font-style:inherit;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight:inherit;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:inherit;
  background-color:transparent;
  list-style-type:none;
}
button,
.button,
input[type=submit]{
  cursor:pointer;
  padding:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border-radius:5px;
  background-color:#eee;
  line-height:24px;
  height:48px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  letter-spacing:2px;
  background-color:#69c;
  color:#fff;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:10px;
  transition: background-color 0.1s, border-color 0.1s, color 0.1s;
}
button:hover,
.button:hover,
input[type=submit]:hover{
  background-color:#7ad;
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button>Foo</button>
    <button>Bar</button>
    <a class="button">Baz</a>
    <input type="submit" value="Yar" />
  </body>
</html>
```

I used `window.getComputedStyle` on `Bar` and `Baz` and then used `vimdiff` to compare the outputs. These were the only differences between the two:

```
#bar{
  align-items: flex-start;
  perspective-origin: 23.5625px;
  transform-origin: 23.5625px 24px;
  -webkit-logical-width: 47.125px;
  width: 47.125px;
}

#baz{
  align-items: stretch;
  perspective-origin: 23.1875px;
  transform-origin: 23.1875px 24px;
  -webkit-logical-width: 46.375px;
  width: 46.375px;
}
```

Neither has perspective nor transform applied, so those should be irrelevant.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Thanks for the edit; was just about to do that.

Comment: @RichardEverett but they all have the same styles applied. What default or browser-specific style could be affecting the anchor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The text of the `<button>` is aligned in the center, but for the `<a>` is aligned at the top. The `vertical-align` applies to the element itself only, not to the text within the element.

The text will be center aligned within the line. So if the `line-height` matches the height of the element (minus padding), than everything is centered.

So the line-height should be `height - padding-top - padding-bottom` = `48px - 10px - 10px` = `28px`

#### CSS

```
button, .button, input[type=submit] {
  line-height: 28px;
}
```

Comment: If the browser is applying these stylistic differences, they should be included in the results of window.getComputedStyle, no? I ran that on Bar and Baz, and the diff indicated nothing incriminating.

Comment: That'll make the `<a>` look different than the `<button>` when they have more than one line of text.

Comment: @RobertAKARobin No, you simply can't style how text is vertically aligned within a block element (see http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html). Therefor it's not showing up in the computed style.  You're stuck with the browsers behavior which is different for an `<a>` and `<button>`.

Comment: @amphetamachine Multiple lines simply won't be displayed, since the `line-height` equals the inner height, which is fix with `height`. This is solution doesn't cause or fix this.

Comment: @Jasny-ArnoldDaniels Well, shoot. CSS-less styling? That shakes my faith in the system!

Answer (score 1):

It's because the elements other than 'a' automatically center the content. Change the height, and you'll see they all stay centered except the anchor. So when you set the padding top, it's making them look the same, but it only works at a certain size.

Comment: Huh. So the browser is effectively applying styles that are _not_ specified in its default stylesheet?

Comment: Pretty much! You may find more clues by inspecting and digging through the styles applied by the user agent stylesheet.

Comment: Those should be factored into the results of `window.getComputedStyle`, no? I ran that on `Bar` and `Baz`, and the `diff` indicated nothing incriminating.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure exactly where the style comes from, but just do a simple test. Increase the height in your demo and you'll see they all stay centered except for the anchor.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the `line-height` applied to the elements, you can fix it by modifying it:

**CSS**

```
button, .button, input[type=submit] {
   line-height: 30px;
}
```

Reason: because you are setting `padding` for the elements, an alternative to your code is to remove the `height` and `line-height` then to use only `padding` like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Buttons</title>
    <style>
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border:0;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  border-spacing:0;
  font-size:inherit;
  font-style:inherit;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight:inherit;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:inherit;
  background-color:transparent;
  list-style-type:none;
}
button,
.button,
input[type=submit]{
  cursor:pointer;
  padding:18px 10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border-radius:5px;
  background-color:#eee;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  letter-spacing:2px;
  background-color:#69c;
  color:#fff;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:10px;
  transition: background-color 0.1s, border-color 0.1s, color 0.1s;
}
button:hover,
.button:hover,
input[type=submit]:hover{
  background-color:#7ad;
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button>Foo</button>
    <button>Bar</button>
    <a class="button">Baz</a>
    <input type="submit" value="Yar" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What the heck. That seems to fix it, but I don't understand why. I specified an identical line-height for all of them of `24px`.

Comment: It is the line height, but it should be `28px`, not `30px`. (height - padding-top - padding-bottom) = 48px - 10px - 10px = 28px.

Comment: But if they all have identical styling, why is one of them displayed differently?

Comment: @amphetamachine please explain more.

Answer (score 0):

The `line-height` declaration only appears to be affecting `.button`.

*(Possibly because the other three elements are all `<form>` elements and so may have **Shadow CSS default styles** pre-applied to them by the browser?)*

Whatever the reason, applying the correct `line-height` to `.button`, fixes the issue.

The height of each element is `48px`

That `48px` includes the padding because of `box-sizing: border-box`

So, to position the text in the vertical middle of `.button`, you need to remove the padding-top (`10px`) and padding-bottom (`10px`) from the height (`48px`).

```
48px - 10px - 10px = 28px
```

**Solution:**

Remove

```
line-height:24px;
```

from

```
button,
.button,
input[type=submit]{
...
}
```

and add

```
.button {
line-height:28px;
}
```

to the styles.

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border:0;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  border-spacing:0;
  font-size:inherit;
  font-style:inherit;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight:inherit;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:inherit;
  background-color:transparent;
  list-style-type:none;
}

button,
.button,
input[type=submit]{
  cursor:pointer;
  padding:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border-radius:5px;
  background-color:#eee;
  height:48px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  letter-spacing:2px;
  background-color:#69c;
  color:#fff;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:10px;
  transition: background-color 0.1s, border-color 0.1s, color 0.1s;
}

.button {
line-height:28px;
}

button:hover,
.button:hover,
input[type=submit]:hover{
  background-color:#7ad;
}
```

```html
<button>Foo</button>
<button>Bar</button>
<a class="button">Baz</a>
<input type="submit" value="Yar" />
```